# Git how to check to which repo project is connected

Tags: git, android-studio

How can I check to see which repo project is connected when I'm using `android studio`?

I have created a new repo in `bitbucket`, pulled that new repository and copied the old project which was connected to another repository to that folder now I want to make sure that I will push to the right repository.

Comment: git remote show origin

Comment: [`git remote -v`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#git-remote--v) lists the remote names and their URLs.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should be able to view your remote repositories by clicking **VCS > Git > Remotes**.

In Android Studio you can also click the Console tab to bring up a terminal. If you have set up remote repositories, `git remote -v` will list them, along with their names.

To make sure you push to the right repository, just make sure you use the right repository name from this list when doing so.

Your output might be as simple as

```
origin  https://github.com/username/myrepo (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/username/myrepo (push)
```

in which case `git push origin master` would push to the master branch of `myrepo`.

If you have multiple remote repositories it might look like

```
origin  https://github.com/username/myrepo (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/username/myrepo (push)
repo2   https://github.com/username2/anotherrepo (fetch)
repo2   https://github.com/username2/anotherrepo (push)
```

in which case you can use `origin` or `repo2` in your push command depending on where you want to commit your changes.